# Is there a way for me to send automatic messages in Discord through my account?

Tags: automation, discord

Basically, I have a personal server. I want to spam another message in every like 10 seconds (so the cooldown will be fine). I don't think it matters, but it's for the poketwo bot (don't judge me). Is there some kind of file so that I can make and run it. Will do it (I'm assuming like a .js file that I can run with cmd)? I haven't really tried anything because I don't really know how most of that stuff works, and searching the web hasn't been any help. I'm on Windows 10. I want it to be sent from my account, not a bot.

Answer (score 1):

You could, but you would need a selfbot. **This is against Discord ToS**, but there are libraries to assist with this. For example, `discord.js-self` allows user tokens, and you could code a selfbot to automate messages like any other bot.

Alternatively, you could try using AutoHotKey, but you'd need to be focused on Discord when you want to auto-type messages.